# Linking Azure DevOps Repos in different projects

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am currently at an organization where we are working on multiple projects that are based on the same code base.  Let's call the code base CB and three projects A,B,C.  Projects A,B,C implement features onto the original CB, but consists of different teams.  Eventually the projects would be merged onto the same code base.  The tool my company is using is Azure DevOps.  It is nice in that each project has its own space with a Wiki to gather/store information and an agile board and backlog to manage sprints.  But each project also has its own code repository as well as Azure Pipelines.  What I could do under other circumstances is work with one code repository and then create three branches.  Periodically the three teams could merge their work onto the main branch to ensure compatibility throughout the projects.  However, as I understand it, in my particular situation it's almost like I would need to somehow link code repositories among different Azure DevOps projects, since each project has an independent code repository.  Either that or there is a totally different approach I am not considering.  What is the best way to approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want to fork your CB repo into each project, which Azure DevOps supports https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio, however this depends on your workflow. If separation of work between teams is the concern then they could all work off the same repo in the same project and use [areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) to separate their backlogs. It's difficult to say without knowing more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the links.  I read through and it seems that both methods could work.  I am trying to understand when it is better to use one method versus the other.  In my case, my company is working on a feature release with a few different features (let's call them A,B,C) and the last code base was the previous release.  The teams working on A,B,C are different, though there are some overlapping members.  If all goes well, then all features will be integrated into the same code base.  However, it is possible that not all features will be integrated (e.g. maybe only A+B make it).

Comment: I guess I am asking under which scenario(s) would it be better to create new projects with a forked repository as opposed to creating one project with area separations (and vice versa)?  I realize there may not be a "right" answer but what would some clearer guidelines be based on your experience?

Comment: What did you end up doing? For different reasons we've run into a similar dilemma, with lots of different projects, and we're trying to figure out how to better combine things. It'd be great to hear more about what other people have tried and what worked (or didn't)